# Python general-purpose caching decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have the following decorator in my script:

```
def cached_to_disk(func):
    """Save the results of the func to the directory specified in datadir."""
    path = datadir + func.__name__
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)

    @wraps(func)
    def cached_func(page):
        fullpath = "{}/{}".format(path, page.url)
        if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
            with open(fullpath) as cached_file:
                data = cached_file.read()
        else:
            data = func(page)
            if data is not None:
                with open(fullpath, "w") as cached_file:
                    cached_file.write(data)
        return data
    return cached_func
```

It works great. However, I now want to extend it work for any function. Somewhat like that:

```
@wraps(func)
def cached_func(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

The problem I have is determining where to save the cache. When I work with my custom Page objects, I can just use the (normalized) url as the filename. However, when `func` can receive arbitrary parameters, it's not as clear how to decide on the filename. I was thinking about using `args[0].__repr__`, but that doesn't sound like a very good idea for functions with multiple arguments (something like `download(site, page_on_the_site)` for example) or without any arguments.

Ideally, I'd like the general-purpose decorator to keep working exactly the same for those functions it already supports.

Is there a simple and robust way to do something like that?

Comment: You could create a cache-key by hashing positional and keyword arguments. See the [Py2.6+ and Py3.0+ backport of Python 3.3's LRU Cache](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578078-py26-and-py30-backport-of-python-33s-lru-cache/) for an example (line 17).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a simple solution that works for any kind of argument.  You would need to serialise the arguments in some way, and not all arguments can be serialised (e.g. closures are usually tricky).  Have a look at the [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) module for something that comes close.

It basically gives you a dictionary-like object, and any object that can be pickled can be uused as a key, so you could use something like `(func.__name__, args, kwargs)`.

Note that this is more general than using a Python dictionary, which requires keys to be hashable.